Quill Mention Integration with PrimeReact Editor Not Working
I am trying to integrate mentions (@) functionality in the PrimeReact Editor component using Quill and the quill-mention module, but it is not working as expected. I have tried multiple approaches to get the mention dropdown inside the editor, but the mention functionality does not trigger, and the mention selection does not insert the correct text inside the editor.
Actual Behavior:
The mention dropdown does not appear when typing @ in the editor.
No mention is inserted into the editor even after selecting a user.
Expected Behavior:
When typing @ in the editor, the dropdown with suggestions (user names) should appear.
Once a user is selected, their mention should be inserted inside the editor content.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
